# Read JSON file and update SQL database

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-bot-service

I have designed a Virtual Assistant using Microsoft Azure services and this is my last step, I just can't figure out how to successfully read from the BLOB storage and output a JSON file, and have another program to read that JSON to update the database.

Here is the program to download BLOB's content and save to a JSON file

```
static async void DownloadConv()
{
    var connectionString = "​";
    var blobContainerName = "transcriptsdev";
    string localPath = "C:\\Downloads\\convdata";

    // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

    // Create the container and return a container client object
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);

    Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");

    // List all blobs in the container
    foreach (Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
        //string fileName = "conv" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
        string fileName = "abc.json";
        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDownloading blob to\n\t{0}\n", localFilePath);
        // Get a reference to a blob
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
        // Download the blob's contents and save it to a file
        BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
        using (FileStream downloadFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath))
        {
            await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream);
            downloadFileStream.Close();
        }
        break;
    }
```

And here is the second program to read the JSON file and update database which I couldn't get it working

```
public static void showData()
{
    sql = "Select FlowID,FlowName from bot.Flow";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Output);
    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    Output = ""; // resets the string so data doesnt pile up
}
public static void insertData()
{
    sql = "Insert into bot.Flow (FlowID,FlowName) values(99,'" + "Where to go for orientaion " + "')";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("\nAdded new record to the DB\n");
}
public static void deleteData()
{
    sql = "Delete bot.Flow where FlowID=99";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("\nDeleted a record from the DB\n");
}
```

All the program works as they are now but I cant' read the json file and store that information in the right database.

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you read the data from `.json` file ?  And  are u sure you have right connectionstrings to connect db?

Comment: no errors and i read the data from .json file. I removed the connectionstrings because it contains confidential information

Comment: I know, I mean you can make sure you can successfully connect to the database, right. My suggestion is to add a record in the database log table or a temporary table when you can read the .json file to ensure that this operation (file reading and database connection) is successful.